# How to write docker-compose file correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created asp.net core MVC app. Configured selfsigned certificate to connect using https and ran it in docker container using this command

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/identitycert.pfx -v ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/ kirillbasic/identityserver
```

I can easily connect to my localhost. But then i tried to use docker-compose.yaml file which looks like this

```
services:
 identityserver:
  image: kirillbasic/identityserver:test
  ports: 
   - "4999:80"
   - "5000:433"
  environment:
   ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+;http://+
   ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 5000
   ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: password
   ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /https/identitycert.pfx
  volumes: ["${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/"]
```

I get "secure connection failed". I tried different ways of typing: with brackets and without them but nothing helps. Does anybody have any suggestions why does it happen and how can i fix this?

Comment: Typo? (443=>433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to regex chars in 3.3 docker-compose version file you would need to surround that variable with single quotes.
Can you try this and see if it works.

```
version: '3.3'
    services:
        identityserver:
            image: kirillbasic/identityserver
            ports:
                - '5000:80'
                - '5001:443'
            environment:
                - 'ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+'
                - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001
                - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
                - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/identitycert.pfx
            volumes:
                - '${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/'
```